# Mongoose asynchronous .save and callback

Tags: asynchronous, mongoose, callback

This is one of those problem that you can explain but do not know how to fix it.  I have a simple `store` method:

```
exports.store = async (req, res) => {
    const mydata = new MyModel(req.body)
    await mydata.save(function(err,user) {
        res.location('/mydata/id/' + user._id)
    })
    res.status(201).json({ data: userdata })
}
```

When it runs, I get the following error:

```
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:489:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:496:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (.../node_modules/express/lib/response.js:730:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (.../node_modules/express/lib/response.js:847:15)
    at .../src/controllers/users-controller.js:26:13
    at .../node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3919:16
    at .../node_modules/mongoose/lib/services/model/applyHooks.js:162:20
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I appears that the callback function runs separately and asynchronously because the `res.status(201).json({ data: userdata })` seems to be producing the error and does not let me set the location header.

I've looked around for how to set the location header but none of the answers are like what I'm trying to do.  This seems like something that should have been done before...?  I'm looking for some help on how to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two way of thinking :

- Promises (with async/await in your case)
- Callback

---

Use only one

---

```
try {
   const user = await mydata.save();

   res.location(`/mydata/id/${user._id}`);

   // Other stuff ...
} catch(err) {
   // Handle the errors
}
```

---

[here](http://erikaybar.name/using-es6-promises-with-mongoosejs-queries/) you get an article about Promises into mongoose.

Comment: Indeed!  I see!  I did not know that you could put the `const user` on the right-hand side.  I though in order to access `user`, you needed to use a callback.  That worked great!  Thanks!